# "Unable to access location, TLS/SSL support not available" when trying to connect to webdav

Tags: networking, nautilus, webdav

When I try to connect to a webdav share in the Nautilus file manager, I am getting the following error:

Unable to access location
HTTP Error: TTLS/SSL support not available; install glib-networking

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y45s.png)

Obviously I do have the glib-networking library installed.

Comment: Then try to install it: `sudo apt install glib-networking` ... or ask your sysadm if your are not allowed on install ´packages.

Comment: As I said it is already installed. When I run that command it just states that 0 new packages are installed.

Comment: Same problem here, if I try to eneter my google account.